# Decoradores avanzados en Python

Tags: python-3.x, decoradores

> **Introducción**
>
> Para elabrorar una respuesta a una pregunta de StackOverflow en Español que, desgraciadamente, fue finalmente borrada por el OP, estuve un rato investigando en la programación de decoradores Python y en particular en uno que fuera lo bastante flexible para adaptarse a una situación especialmente compleja.
>
> Aunque la pregunta fue borrada, creo que lo que aprendí elaborando la respuesta puede ser útil a alguien más y me parece una pena que se pierda, así que replanteo aquí la pregunta, ligeramente modificada para no perjudicar al OP que hizo la pregunta original y la borró.

Se trata de implementar un decorador que pueda ser utilizado para que la función decorada pueda validar si ha recibido o no ciertos parámetros en un diccionario.

Por ejemplo, esta sería la función que recibe el diccionario:

```
def funcion_ejemplo(data={}, prefijo="<div>", sufijo="</div>"):
  return f"{prefijo}{data['item']} x {data['cantidad']}{sufijo}"
```

Que se podría invocar por ejemplo así:

```
cadena = funcion_ejemplo({'item': 'tornillo', 'cantidad': 6})
```

y produciría la cadena `"<div>tornillo x 6</div>"`.

Naturalmente si a esta función no se le pasa el diccionario correcto (es decir, uno que no tenga el campo `"item"` o el campo `"cantidad"`, la función romperá. En un caso general podría dar incluso resultados incorrectos. Queremos añadir a la función código que verifique si ha recibido los datos correctos y en caso contrario genere una excepción `ValueError`. Para este ejemplo particular esa validación se haría así:

```
  # ...
  for campo in ["item", "cantidad"]:
       if campo not in data or not data[campo]:  # (el campo existe pero viene vacío)
          raise(ValueError(f"Falta el campo {campo} en el diccionario"))
```

Se trataría ahora de delegar ese trabajo en un decorador que podemos llamar `required_data` de modo que pueda usarse así:

```
@required_data("item", "cantidad")
def funcion_ejemplo(data={}, prefijo="<div>", sufijo="</div>"):
  return f"{prefijo}{data['item']} x {data['cantidad']}{sufijo}"
```

¿Cómo se programaría un decorador así?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El decorador que se pide es muy complejo por varias razones:

- Es un decorador que recibe parámetros. Esto de por sí ya añade una complejidad conceptual importante, porque el decorador debe definir una función interna que al ser ejecutada devuelva a su vez un decorador, por lo que esa función interna deberá definir a su vez otra función interna, que será el decorador final.
- El número de parámetros a recibir por el decorador es variable. En el ejemplo son dos: `"item", "cantidad"`, pero cabe suponer que pueda recibir cualquier otra cantidad de campos a validar.
- La función que se quiere decorar tiene valores por defecto entre sus parámetros, lo que complica la implementación del *wrapper*.

Hacer un buen decorador robusto y genérico que pueda copar con todo esto es complicado y el resultado necesariamente feo y bastante ilegible. Así que vamos por pasos.

### Versión inicial simplista

Vamos a suponer de momento que siempre que se llame a la función una vez decorada se le va a pasar el parámetro `data`. Eso nos libera del problema de que se pueda invocar así  simplemente con `funcion_ejemplo()`, lo que de momento facilitará la implementación del decorador.

En este caso el decorador que se busca podría ser como sigue (he incluido comentarios para tratar de explicar --y explicarme-- la complejidad):

```py
def required_data(*args):

  # Este es el wrapper que recibe como parámetro la función a decorar
  def _wrapper(f):
    # Dentro hay otro decorador
    # Este es el código que se ejecutará al llamar a la funcion decorada
    def verify_and_call(*inner_args):
      # *inner_args son los parámetros
      req_data = args          # Tomamos del closure ("item", "cantidad")
      data = inner_args[0]     # Sacar el primer parámetro que se le pasa a f
      # Realizar la validación
      for d in req_data:
        if d not in data or not data[d]:
          raise(ValueError(f"Falta el campo '{d}' en el diccionario"))

      # Si la validación pasa, podemos invocar a la función f y pasarle los
      # mismos parámetros, retornando el resultado que devuelva f
      return f(*inner_args)

    # El _wrapper retorna la función que acabamos de definir
    return verify_and_call

  # El decorador retorna el _wrapper
  return _wrapper
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```py
@required_data("item", "cantidad")
def funcion_ejemplo(data={}, prefijo="<div>", sufijo="</div>"):
  "La función puede tener una documentación en forma de docstring"
  return f"{prefijo}{data['item']} x {data['cantidad']}{sufijo}"
```

Demostración de que funciona:

```py
>>> item1 = {"item": "tornillo", "cantidad": 6}
>>> item2 = {"item": "tuerca" }  # Falta cantidad, es erróneo
>>> funcion_ejemplo(item1)
'<div>tornillo x 6</div>'
>>> funcion_ejemplo(item2)
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
ValueError: Falta el campo 'cantidad' en el diccionario
```

Sin embargo, si no le pasamos parámetros falla de una forma rara:

```py
>>> funcion_ejemplo()
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
---> 10       data = inner_args[0]     # Sacar el parámetro que se le pasa a f

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Efectivamente, al no pasarle parámetro `*inner_args` llega vacío, y el intento de acceder a su elemento `[0]` produce una excepción.

Por otro lado tampoco funciona bien si le pasamos el parámetro por nombre:

```py
>>> funcion_ejemplo(data=item1)
Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 funcion_ejemplo(data=person1)

TypeError: verify_and_call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

Efectivamente lo que ocurre ahora es que al haber definido `verify_and_call()` de modo que recibe solo parámetros posicionales (`*inner_args`), no nos deja pasarle parámetros con nombre.

Podríamos pensar en arreglarlo añadiéndole otro parámetro `**kwargs`, pero seguiríamos en problemas porque en todo caso el parámetro `data` no estaría en `inner_args[0]` como la función supone.

### Segunda versión, manejando parámetros posicionales o con nombre

Si añadimos a `verify_and_call()` la posibilidad de recibir `**kwargs`, entonces puede que `data` esté en `*inner_args` si se pasó por posición, o en `**kwargs` si se pasó por nombre. De modo que el código debe buscar en ambos sitios:

```py
def required_data(*args):

  # Este es el wrapper que recibe como parámetro la función a decorar
  def _wrapper(f):
    # Dentro hay otro decorador
    # Este es el código que se ejecutará al llamar a la funcion decorada
    def verify_and_call(*inner_args, **kwargs):
      # *inner_args son los parámetros
      req_data = args          # Tomamos del closure ("item", "cantidad")
      if "data" in kwargs:
        data = kwargs["data"]
      elif len(inner_args)>0:
        data = inner_args[0]
      else:
        raise(ValueError(f"Falta el parámetro data"))
      # Realizar la validación
      for d in req_data:
        if d not in data or not data[d]:
          raise(ValueError(f"Falta el campo '{d}' en el diccionario"))

      # Si la validación pasa, podemos invocar a la función f y pasarle los
      # mismos parámetros, retornando el resultado que devuelva f
      return f(*inner_args, **kwargs)

    # El _wrapper retorna la función que acabamos de decfinir
    return verify_and_call

  # El decorador retorna el _wrapper
  return _wrapper
```

Observa cómo se mira si "data" está en `kwargs` y si no se intenta tomar de `inner_args` y si tampoco está se eleva una excepción. Observa también cómo en la llamada a `f()` se le pasa también `**kwargs` por si es ahí donde venía `data`.

Ahora ya funciona con parámetros con nombre, o posicionales:

```py
>>> funcion_ejemplo(item1)
'<div>tornillo x 6</div>'
>>> funcion_ejemplo(data=item1)
'<div>tornillo x 6</div>'
```

pero sigue fallando si no pasamos parámetros (aunque esta vez es porque elevamos a propósito una excepción señalándolo):

```py
>>> funcion_ejemplo()
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
ValueError: Falta el parámetro data
```

Esto está bastante mejor, pero nos impide decorar una función que reciba un parámetro por defecto, como este:

```py
@required_data("item", "cantidad")
def funcion_ejemplo(data={"item": "noname", "cantidad": 1}, prefijo="<div>", sufijo="</div>"):
  "La función puede tener una documentación en forma de docstring"
  return f"{prefijo}{data['item']} x {data['cantidad']}{sufijo}"
```

Aquí estamos pasando como valor por defecto a `data` un diccionario que debería validar correctamente pues tiene `"item"` y `"cantidad"`, pero en realidad la validación ni siquiera llega a realizarse si llamamos `funcion_ejemplo()` sin parámetros, porque nuestro decorador espera un parámetro llamado `data` y no se lo estamos pasando.

Hay otro detalle menor, y es que al envolver la función de este modo se pierde el *docstring* de la función original:

```py
>>> help(funcion_ejemplo)
Help on function verify_and_call in module __main__:

verify_and_call(*inner_args, **kwargs)
```

En vez de darnos la ayuda sobre la función `funcion_ejemplo()` nos está mostrando la de su envoltorio, `verify_and_call()`

### Última versión, valores por defecto y docstrings

Para resolver el problema del docstring usaremos `functools.wraps()` que sirve para que se copie el prototipo y documentación de la función decorada a la función decoradora.

Para poder acceder al valor por defecto de `data` en la función decorada usaremos `inspect.signature`.

Esta es la versión final del decorador:

```py
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

# Este es el decorador "externo". 
# args es la lista de parámetros que se le pasa al decorador
# por ejemplo ("name", "last_name")
def required_data(*args):

  # Este es el wrapper que recibe como parámetro la función a decorar
  def _wrapper(f):
    sig = signature(f)   # Obtener la declaración y lista de parámetros de f
    @wraps(f)     # Esto es para preservar nombre y docstring de la función decorada
      # Este es el código que se ejecutará al llamar a la funcion decorada
    def verify_and_call(*inner_args, **kwargs):
      # inner_args y kwargs son los parámetros con los que se invocará a la
      # función decorada
      req_data = args           # Tomamos del closure ("item", "cantidad")
      if inner_args:            # Sacamos el parámetro "data" de la función decorada
        data = inner_args[0]    # Pudo pasarsele como el primer argumento posicional
      elif "data" in kwargs:    # o como un argumento por nombre
        data = kwargs["data"]
      elif "data" in sig.parameters:    # o estar en la lista de valores por defecto de f
        data = sig.parameters["data"].default
      else:                     # o no estar en ningún sitio
        raise(ValueError(f"Falta el parámetro data"))
      # Realizar la validación
      for d in req_data:
        if d not in data or not data[d]:
          raise(ValueError(f"Falta el campo '{d}' en el diccionario"))

      # Si la validación pasa, podemos invocar a la función f y pasarle los
      # mismos parámetros, retornando el resultado que devuelva f
      return f(*inner_args, **kwargs)

    # El _wrapper retorna la función que acabamos de decfinir
    return verify_and_call

  # El decorador retorna el _wrapper
  return _wrapper
```

Se usa exactamente igual que los anteriores:

```py
@required_data("item", "cantidad")
def funcion_ejemplo(data={}, prefijo="<div>", sufijo="</div>"):
  "La función puede tener una documentación en forma de docstring"
  return f"{prefijo}{data['item']} x {data['cantidad']}{sufijo}"
```

y podemos comprobar que soporta ya todas las características deseadas:

```py
>>> # No le paso parámetro, rompe porque el parámetro por defecto es {} que no tiene "item"
>>> funcion_ejemplo()
[...]
ValueError: Falta el campo 'item' en el diccionario


>>> # Parámetro por posicion y por nombre
>>> funcion_ejemplo(data=item1)
'<div>tornillo x 6</div>'
>>> funcion_ejemplo(item1)
'<div>tornillo x 6</div>'


>>> # La ayuda funciona
>>> help(funcion_ejemplo)
Help on function funcion_ejemplo in module __main__:

funcion_ejemplo(data={}, prefijo='<div>', sufijo='</div>')
    La función puede tener una documentación en forma de docstring
```

También funciona correctamente si decoramos una función que tiene en `data` un valor por defecto válido:

```py
@required_data("item", "cantidad")
def funcion_ejemplo(data={"item": "noname", "cantidad": 1}, prefijo="<div>", sufijo="</div>"):
  "La función puede tener una documentación en forma de docstring"
  return f"{prefijo}{data['item']} x {data['cantidad']}{sufijo}"


>>> funcion_ejemplo()
'<div>noname x 1</div>'
```